# What is the angular speed of mass $m$ if we pull the string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, angular-momentum, work

[image]

> Mass $m$ is rotating on a horizontal friction-less plane around a tiny hole. A massless string is connected to mass $m$ and the other end of it is held by John's hand. John pulls the string to move the mass to radius $r_2$, what is the angular speed $(\omega_2)$ of mass $m$?

---

I have 2 approaches to this:

**1. Work & Energy approach:** $$\int_{r_1}^{r_2} F \, dr = \frac{1}2m(r_2\ \omega_2)^2 - \frac{1}2m(r_1\ \omega_1)^2$$
If substitute moment of inertia of mass m around the hole $$I=mr^2$$  we will have $$\int_{r_1}^{r_2} F \, dr = \frac{1}2I_2\ \omega_2^2 - \frac{1}2I_1\ \omega_1^2$$ So $ω_2$ can be calculated from this last equation.

**2. Conservation of angular momentum:** since there is no torque applied on mass $m$ (the tension of string is always in the direction of the hole; it doesn’t not create a torque). So, the angular momentum of mass $m$ around the centre (hole) is conserved. So, $$I_1\ \omega_1= I_2\ \omega_2$$ and $ω_2$ can be calculated from this equation.

---

Why $ω_2$ we calculate from these 2 approaches are different? How would you explain two different answers to the same question from two approaches above?

Comment: @Butane, correct your statement. Angular momentum is constant about the center of the circle but energy the energy of the system is not since work is to be done to pull the ball.

Comment: -@Ebi, no information about $F$ is given in the question whether it constant or variable.

Comment: @Butane Hi. I never said energy is conserved. In 1 st approach, energy of the mass changes by the work done on it.

Comment: @SarGe That does not matter, you can suppose a variable F, still the two answers will be different.

Comment: This is essentially a repost of [a question that has already been closed once](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/571735/what-is-the-angular-speed-of-the-mass-m-if-we-pull-the-string) because it violates the homework and exercises policy.  @Ebi please don't do this here.

Comment: @Thorondor I am not a student my friend. This is NOT a homework. I thought about it and designed it myself. The question was closed once because I did not know how to type formula in here so I had typed the question in Word and posted it here.

Comment: While Chris commented on your question about the picture, the reason for closure was that it was *homework-like*, not because you hadn't typed the text in the picture.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This question is not a homework mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is wrong because you are not considering a radial velocity to the ball, at $r_2$. Let this velocity be $v$. Work energy theorem is as follows:
$$\int_{r_1}^{r_2} F \, dr=\frac{1}{2}I_2\omega_2^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{1}{2}I_1\omega_1^2$$
I don't see any way to proceed with the solution with this approach, after including $v$ in the energy.

The second approach is correct, because the net torque on the mass about the hole is zero. The radial velocity doesn't affect angular momentum.
$$\boxed{I_1\omega_1=I_2\omega_2}$$

Comment: At state 2, when we stop pulling the string, the mass is just rotating on a circle with the radius r2 (with no radial speed). Am I missing something?

Comment: If you stop pulling the string, it will not continue circularly (unless you pulled the string quasi-statically!). Consider this: you pulled it really hard and released the moment it came to $r_2$. Obviously it will not continue circularly.

Comment: right. It is pulled quasi-statically. How would you explain it?

Comment: @Ebi if it is pulled quasi-statically, the work done by $F$ is $\int_{r_1}^{r_2} m\omega^2r \, dr$. To calculate this integral, you ultimately have to conserve angular momentum. Doing this is the same as conserving between the $2$ final states, as in approach 2. You cannot get away with not conserving angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

As net external torque is zero so here you can apply conservation of angular momentum to calculate angular velocity i.e IW = CONSTANT.

Comment: How about work-energy approach?